# Allowing the repr() of my class's instances to be parsed by eval()

Tags: python, serialization, eval

Say I have defined a class myself and I defined a `__repr__` method for it. I want to about convert it back to my object. I know that object serialization may be a good way of doing so (using the `json` module) but is there anyway I can use the built-in `eval` function to achieve this?

Comment: I am sorry for ambiguity here, What I mean is I want to make my object eval-able here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your `__repr__()` so it creates a valid Python expression for instantiating your object.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r, %r)" % (type(self).__name__, self.a, self.b)
```

Obviously this relies on the values you're using having their own reasonable `repr()`.

You don't have to define any special `eval()`—just pass in whatever you get from `repr()`.

Comment: if you try this, you will get an error saying NameError: name 'instance' is not defined

Comment: There is not anything called `instance` in that code, so that's not where that error is coming from.

Comment: @kindall: he's probably using an old-style class.